# Im trying to use importxml in google sheets to get a stock price from google finance, struggling with xml elements and syntax

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

I'm trying to use the `IMPORTXML()` function in google sheets to get a current stock price from Yahoo finance, anyway, I have a pretty decent understanding of google app script and java but no XML background what-so-ever.

From the [link](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY?p=SPY) I'm trying to get the stock current stock price.

Using the Inspector in google chrome I get these values as follows of the element I need aka "stock price" values as follows:

copy xpath returns :

> //*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]  ;

copy full xpath returns:

> /html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]  ;

copy element returns:

```
<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="52">298.88</span> ;
```

I'm wondering if using part or all of any of those XML codes will return the price ( current price is 298.88 as in the copy element section)

to the best of my knowledge using `=IMPORTXML`("Link goes here", XML code goes here") will return what I need.

I just don't know if I'm wrong or what part of code to use 
thanks in advance.

my best guess as to what i need but returns false is :

```
=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY?p=SPY","data-reactid='52'")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `=IMPORTXML()` function takes as parameters a URL and an [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). In your formula, the `"data-reactid='52'` is not a valid XPath.

The following Sheets formula attained the desired result for me:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY?p=SPY","//*[@id=""quote-header-info""]/div[2]/div[1]/span")
```

As you can see here:

[image: Formula result]

#### Disclaimer

You have to consider that the XPath you get in Google Chrome's devtools is obtained based on the current page status (i.e. after the Javascript code has been parsed and executed). When using `=IMPORTXML()` function, the engine does **not** execute the code, thus the XPath you get from the devtools may not work as expected in your Sheets document.

Answer (score 0):

Try below, mind the punctuation mark for 'quote-header-info'.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY?p=SPY","//*[@id='quote-header-info']/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]")
```

Answer (score -2):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MWe-aTZFxSQ5IiMyTZrh1HJzQ5Zm3vMJyx6T_5jRVaQ/edit#gid=0

set cell A2 = https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY?p=SPY
set cell A3 = //*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]

set cell A5 = IMPORTXML(A2,A3)

Comment: The link you have added denies access... Please grant public access to the link